# jQuery: how to choose options in another selection based off a class in the first selection

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to show drop down options in a second selection drop down menu based off the selection made on the first drop down menu.  In this example, the first drop down menu has 3 selections each with their own unique class.  The second dropdown menu has several drop down options with class values that match the class values from the first drop down.  By default, the 2nd drop down options are hidden until the user chooses a drop down option from the first selection.  My goal is that once the user makes there selection from the first drop down option, to then add a class of "display_block" to the options in the 2nd drop down menu that have the same class value made from the selection in the first drop down box.

Here is the HTML:

```
<label class="label_bra_band_size">
<span class="store_level_3_brasize">Band Size</span></label>
<select id="product_band_size" name="band_size">
<option value="">Select Band Size</option>
<option value="32" class="a293">32</option>
<option value="34" class="a310">34</option>
<option value="36" class="a323">36</option>
</select>

<label class="label_cup_size">
<span class="store_level_3_brasize">Cup Size</span></label>
<select id="product_cup_size" name="cup_size">
<option value="">Select Cup Size</option>
<option value="A" class="a293" style="display:none;">A</option>
<option value="B" class="a293" style="display:none;">B</option>
<option value="C" class="a293" style="display:none;">C</option>
<option value="D" class="a310" style="display:none;">D</option>
<option value="E" class="a310" style="display:none;">E</option>
<option value="F" class="a310" style="display:none;">F</option>
<option value="G" class="a323" style="display:none;">G</option>
<option value="H" class="a323" style="display:none;">H</option>
<option value="I" class="a323" style="display:none;">I</option>
</select>
```

Here is the jQuery below. Here's my logic in the jQuery: when someone makes a selection from the first option, we store the selection class in a variable (ProductBandSize).  Then in the 2nd part we compare the options in the 2nd drop down against the variable value.  If the 2nd dropdown option has the same class as the variable, add a class of "display_block".  Unfortunately all the options in the 2nd drop down class are getting the class value of "display_block".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#product_band_size").change(function(){
    //When the user changes the Band size, get the Cup Size and assign it to a variable
    var ProductBandSize = $("#product_band_size option:selected").attr("class");
    //Compare the Product Cup Size options against the variable "ProductBandSize"
    if ($("#product_cup_size option").hasClass(ProductBandSize)) {
        //If the product cup size option has the same class value as the first option selected add class display_block to it.
        $("#product_cup_size option").addClass("display_block");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: take in consideration that display:none doesn't work in ie for options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `filter` to find the matching `option` which has that class and then add the class. `hasClass` will only say true/false if the class is present or not. Try this

```
$("#product_band_size").change(function(){
    //When the user changes the Band size, get the Cup Size and assign it to a variable
    var ProductBandSize = $("#product_band_size option:selected").attr("class");
    //Compare the Product Cup Size options against the variable "ProductBandSize"

    $("#product_cup_size option").filter("."+ProductBandSize).addClass("display_block");

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The phrase `$("#product_cup_size option").hasClass(ProductBandSize)` will always be true and `$("#product_cup_size option").addClass("display_block")` will set the class on all the options in the dropdown.

Try

```
$("#product_cup_size option").find('.' + ProductBandSize).addClass("display_block");
```

instead of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just say:

```
$('#product_cup_size option').hide();
$('#product_cup_size option.' + ProductBandSize).show();
```

Really, let jQuery do the work for you.

Comment: i just tried this in safari and chrome.  they don't support it apparently (not sure why), but FF does :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCWvJ/11/) Use .show() and .hide() instead of explicitly setting the CSS display properties ( even though show() and hide() do this in the background ).